# jQuery closest and checking checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am sorry for title. I just need someone see my code. There is some HTML structure:

```
<table id="tableId">
  <tr id="tr1">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td><input class="filter" type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr2">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td><input class="filter" type="checkbox" checked></td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
<button id="print" type="button">Print</button>
```

I want to check every checked checkbox in the table and get the row id. I am using jQuery :

```
$('#print').click(function () {
    var projects = [];
    $('.filter:checked').each(function () {
       var projectId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
       console.log(projectId);
       projects.push({
          Id: projectId
       });
    });
});
```

But the console says `projectId is undefined`. Did I forget something?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `id` is not an attribute but a property. Have you tried `.prop('id')` instead of `.attr('id')`?

Comment: Your code works fine without making any changes; see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5cv6vxv/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, I just had to close the  elements:

```
<table id="tableId">
  <tr id="tr1">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Text</td>
      <td><input class="filter" type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr2">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td><input class="filter" type="checkbox" checked /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="print" type="button">Print</button>
```

See the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rtubio/vy02ppgz/

Comment: Confirmed, works in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: The code worked fine without making any changes, so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The <input> tags weren't closed, so the HTML code might not have worked depending on the validation carried out by the navigator.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. If my row is dynamic when inserted, can it caused the problem? I had closed the tag, but still not working, I see the fiddle works successfully.

Comment: @andrefadila, if the row is not there when you look for it, then that might be the problem. Can you explain better how the table is dynamically generated? Including some additional code might help.

Comment: Thanks @Ricardo, actually the code not different too far, I just doing row insertion loop above, then declare click event after insertion.